# php oop is there way to automatically set this array

Tags: php, oop

for example this `$name = pulic $wherever;` so I can call, for example, `wherever->wherever;`

so that I don't have to type this name every time I add the variables

```
// If it's going to need the database, then it's 
// probably smart to require it before we start.
require_once('database.php');

class Logs extends DatabaseObject {

protected static $table_name="logs";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'ip', 'time', 'page');



public $id;
public $username;
public $ip;
public $time;
public $page;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Have you looked at `__get`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

```
extract( $db_fields );
```

Then you won't need to declare them one by one.

```
class Logs extends DatabaseObject {

protected static $table_name="logs";
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'ip', 'time', 'page');

extract( $db_fields );
```

Comment: i just done this way i think it works fine